# Changing type from class "list" to integer

Tags: python, type-conversion

I am getting an error when changing the type from class 'list' to integer. The error I am getting looks like this

```
des = int(ces)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'.
```

Code:

```
print('Please enter a latitude or longitude value in DMS or DD format.')
a = [int(x) for x in input("Please enter DMS or DD in integer format: ").split(',')]

if len(a) == 3:
   d,b,c = a
   dd = float(d) + float(b)/60 + float(c)/(60*60);
   print("The input value is in DMS form and the DD is", dd)

elif len(a) == 1:
   ces = str(a)
   des = int(ces)
   md = abs(ces - des) * 60
   m = int(md)
   sd = (md - m) * 60
   print[des, m, sd]
else: print("Incorrect input format")
```

Comment: The line `d = int(c)` does not occur in your code.

Comment: Try it with `ces = str(a[0])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you try to coerce a container of objects (here: a list) into a type for numbers (here: integer). But now matter how long and how often you are trying to make that physical coffee cup taste like the Americano inside, it ain't the real thing and you really want to have the good stuff inside that cup.

To get it, you need to access the first list element, as I have pointed out in my comments. For instance,

```
a = [42.42]
```

is a list containing the number 42.42. This list is like a cup of coffee containing delicious espresso (note: the delicious liquid inside the not-so delicious paper-stuff). If you want to get that number you are after (the content of the container), you need to do

```
a[0]
> 42.42
```

Now that you have the number, you can get the integer part:

```
int(a[0])
> 42
```

and subtract it again:

```
a[0] - int(a[0])
> 0.42
```

At least I assume that this is what you are trying to do. I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The list a is a list of integers. I don't know why you'd want to turn that into a string and then back into an integer, but:

```
>>>> str([0]) 
'[0]'
```

Then, trying to turn that into an integer again fails:

```
>>>> int('[0]')
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[0]'
```

Even if it worked, the next step would be meaningless because it would always be 0:

```
ces = str(a[0])
des = int(ces)
md = abs(a[0] - a[0]) * 60 # This is always 0
```

I'm not entirely sure what your code is supposed to do tbh.

Comment: I am having the user input Degree minutes seconds or decimal degrees and then it is supposed to defer to either the if/else statements. If I don't change the type I get this error. TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

Comment: So if len(a) is 1, then the user has entered a single value which you've cast to an integer. I'm not sure what the math you're doing is supposed to be for, because you have only one value and it's an integer. Subtracting it from itself will always be 0. Your problem isn't the python syntax, it's the underlying logic I think.

Comment: I am not sure I need it to be out of the list to go into the mathematical portion and its not.